# Create a table with multiple arrays PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I got 2 arrays. The task is to make multiple columns. First a column called "Naam", then "Rugnummers" and then "Goals". These columns need to be filled with the information of these two arrays in it. First the value of Players, then the key of Goals Or Players (both the same) and then the value of Goals. Here are the two arrays.

```
<?php
//Opdracht 15
$goals = [
3 => 1,
5 => 5,
6 => 0,
7 => 2,
9 => 0,
12 => 4,
14 => 1,
17 => 3,
18 => 1,
19 => 0,
21 => 5,
22 => 0,
23 => 2,
24 => 3,
28 => 1,
30 => 0
    ];
  $players = [
3 => 'Hendrik Leegsta',
5 => 'Jan Hilverda',
6 => 'Hans Worst',
7 => 'Steven Sterk',
9 => 'Willy Wortel',
12 => 'Flip Flierefluiter',
14 => 'Louis Visser',
17 => 'Aram Harakisjoen',
18 => 'Vladimir de Groot',
19 => 'Thomes Thijssen',
21 => 'Arie van der Linde',
22 => 'Ruben Leegstra',
23 => 'Stijn Voorst',
24 => 'Louis Finn',
28 => 'Jürgen Ultz',
30 => 'Giel de Vries'
   ];

?>
    ?>
<html>

 <style>
 table, th, td{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;

 }
 </style>
 <table>
  <tr>
  <th>Naam</th>
  <th>Rugnummer</th>
   <th>Doelpunten</th>
   </tr>


  <?php foreach ($players as $backnumber => $names) {?>
  <tr>
  <td> <?php echo $names;?> </td>
  <td><?php echo $backnumber;?> </td>
  </tr>
  <?php  } ?>
  <?php foreach ($goals as $backnumbers => $scores) { ?>
  <tr>


    <td><?php echo $scores;?> </td>
    </tr>
<?php  } ?>
   </tr>


</table>
  </html>
```

Comment: And your question is what?

Comment: How do I input them into a table. Cause I can only put two of them next to each other, but the third one is always underneath it.

Comment: The code you posted does not output anything. If you have code that actually _does_ something, then post it. Add it to the question. There is an `edit` link below it. _Use it._

Comment: Better???????????????

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Opdracht 15
$goals = [
 3 => 1,
 5 => 5,
 6 => 0,
 7 => 2,
 9 => 0,
 12 => 4,
 14 => 1,
 17 => 3,
 18 => 1,
 19 => 0,
 21 => 5,
 22 => 0,
 23 => 2,
 24 => 3,
 28 => 1,
 30 => 0
];
$players = [
 3 => 'Hendrik Leegsta',
 5 => 'Jan Hilverda',
 6 => 'Hans Worst',
 7 => 'Steven Sterk',
 9 => 'Willy Wortel',
 12 => 'Flip Flierefluiter',
 14 => 'Louis Visser',
 17 => 'Aram Harakisjoen',
 18 => 'Vladimir de Groot',
 19 => 'Thomes Thijssen',
 21 => 'Arie van der Linde',
 22 => 'Ruben Leegstra',
 23 => 'Stijn Voorst',
 24 => 'Louis Finn',
 28 => 'Jürgen Ultz',
 30 => 'Giel de Vries'
];

    ?>
    <html>

     <style>
     table, th, td{
     border: 1px solid black;
     border-collapse: collapse;

     }
     </style>

<?php echo "<table>"; ?>
<?php echo "<tr><th>Naam</th><th>Nummer</th><th>Goals</th></tr>"; ?>
<?php foreach($players as $playerid => $naam){ ?>
    <?php echo "<tr>"; ?>
    <?php $goalcount = $goals[$playerid]; ?>
    <?php echo "<td>$naam</td><td>$playerid</td><td>$goalcount</td>"; ?>
    <?php echo "</tr>";?>
<?php } ?>


    </table>
      </html>
```